# Расставить 8 ферзей так, чтобы они не были под ударом друг друга

Tags: c++, шахматы

Задача поставлена следующим образом: нужно на шахматном поле расставить 8 ферзей так, чтобы они не были под ударом друг друга.

Я реализовал эту задачу на С++ вот так:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int q[8], c, i;
    int count = 1;
    q[0] = 0;
    c = 0;


NC:
    c++;
    if (c == 8) goto print;
    q[c] = -1;


NR:
    q[c]++;
    if (q[c] == 8) goto back;

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if ((q[i] == q[c]) || ((c - i) == abs(q[c] - q[i]))) goto NR;
    }
    goto NC;


back:
    c--;
    if (c == -1) return 0;
    goto NR;

print:
    cout << "---------------------------------";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (j == q[i]) {
                cout << "| Ф ";
            }
            else {
                cout << "|   ";
            }
        }
        cout << "|";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------";
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, как можно исправить мой код, что бы не использовать `goto`? Буду благодарен за решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох, как же тяжко переделывать чужой код...

Так, чисто тупо переделать — можно так:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int q[8] = {};
    for(int c = 1; c != 8; ++c)
    {
        q[c] = -1;
        for(bool ok = false;!ok;)
        {
            if (++q[c] == 8)
            {
                if (--c == -1) return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ok = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
                    if (q[i] == q[c] ||
                        c - i == abs(q[c] - q[i]))
                    {
                        ok = false;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "---------------------------------";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (j == q[i]) {
                cout << "| Q ";
            }
            else {
                cout << "|   ";
            }
        }
        cout << "|";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Но это переделка так себе... Лучше сразу писать под циклы или рекурсию.

P.S. Кстати, задачка настолько небольшая, что быстро работает даже перебор — всего 8! вариантов...

Comment: Спасибо Вам БОЛЬШОЕ!